# Which is correct to ignore dividing/logarithm of zero number in denominator

Tags: matlab

I have stuck when implement the equation

```
c=SN/SD;
b=log(SD)
```

where SN, SD are number. However, the equation will be wrong if `SD=0`,to handle with that issue. I have three ways

First way:

```
c=SN/(SD+(SD==0))
b=log(SD+(SD==0))
```

Second way

```
c=SN/(SD+(SD==0)*eps)
b=log(SD+(SD==0)*eps)
```

Third way

```
c=SN/(SD+eps);
b=log(SD+eps)
```

Which one is more accuracy and correct for my problem? Thank in advance.

For my knowledge, I think that the true answer are

```
c=SN/(SD+(SD==0))
b=log(SD+(SD==0))
```

Comment: Just wondering, what do you want c and b to be when SD = 0? These three ways are not exactly identical.

Comment: when SD==0 then c=0 ,b=0 sir.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually get the 'image-processing' and 'calculus' tag, but I guess you know what you're doing.....but putting that aside, the answer depends on what you expect to be the result:

1. In your first solution you replace 0 with 1, which is mathematically and logically speaking incorrect (1/0 ~= 1/1), but some applications may require it that way.
2. Your 2nd solution is basically the same as the 3rd one IFF SD==0, but may have different results otherwise ([eps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). I wouldn't recommend this approach, as it may result in (maybe expected, but) unwanted values.
3. I don't know which version of Matlab you have, but Matlab is quite foolproof, so you can happily divide by zero (or log 0) and the result will be ±Inf...it may not be strictly correct, but for many engineering/plotting problems it is sufficient.
4. Simply use [If](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) statement.

As I said...the answer depends on what you exactly want from your application and what result you expect. I'm also sure there are more ways to do it, but I think sometimes(!) simple 'if ' is better then not-so-easy-to-read optimization.

Comment: Was writing somethink like this! The 2nd or 3rd answer can be used if you don't care about continuity (2nd) or precision of the values (3rd).

Comment: Thank you LStarling. I think If is not so best choise but It is easy way. My expected result is when SD==0 then c=0 ,b=0 sir.

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior I agree...also division by 0 is not so sensitive to minor changes like + eps, but log(eps) and log(0) is waaay too different I think :D

Comment: ou, and user8430: I think 'if ' statements are very beautiful when your variables have self-explanatory names and still useful when they do not :) I don't see a reason not to use that to solve your problem and since you expect these specific results, it's surely the very simple way of doing it